# Set Control Attributes

Tags: vba, ms-access

looking to set access control attributes using VBA code.
me.ControlName.TabStop=True
What i want is to assign the .TabStop to a variable and then apply to control

```
Dim CtrAction as ??????????

CtrAction=TabStop
'or
CtrAction=Active
'or
CtrAction=Visable

me.ControlName.CtrAction = True
```

I tried various code but did not get anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach:

```
Dim ctrAction As String 
ctrAction = "TabStop"
Me.ControlName.Properties(ctrAction) = True
```

That code as is hardly has any practical use. If you intend to pass different properties as variable input to some procedure, probably have to pass property value as a variable as well. The problem is, property values are a variety of types. TabStop takes a Boolean value, other properties take strings, and some take a number even if you see text in the Properties dialog. As an example, BackColor can be coded as follows.

```
Me.ControlName.BackColor = 16776960
Me.ControlName.BackColor = RGB(000,255,255)
Me.ControlName.BackColor = vbCyan
```

However, the Properties window will show **#00FFFF**.

Another:

```
Me.ControlName.FontName = "Arial Black"
```